Communication between client and cloud service provider?
given different cloud providers there are instances when a service is down or under construction, meaning that other dependant services of the provider might be affected and as such the client (could be a developer) would need assistance from a support agent from the provider. My goal would be if I could find a dataset of such interactions, where a client has communicated with a support agent regarding an issue (could be dependancy, could be new configuration etc etc etc).
I would appreciate all similar sources too.
My goal would be to compare performance of LLM agents compared to real life agents (this part will be deduced by me) if they detected/resolved the same issues.
Thank you in advance.
